Does anyone know what type is screw this is?

the inner screw part

The whole screw next to a penny for scale

I suppose the question is why does it have both an inner and outer head?  Can you include a better picture of the inner one?  Or describe it, as it's hard to photograph.  Is there a hole all the way through the screw?

I added  another photo of the inner screw. I’m not sure haha I don’t know much about screws just know I need a replacement asap also no hole throw the middle just an Allen Rench socket

Looks like a hole for an Allen key, to me

These are washer head screws. Combined with a rubber gasket, used on washing machines. Didn't find any with an Allen key socket. Do these mount into some sort of recess where a socket wrench would not work?

They are for an office chair!!

It's the function, not the article. If you find the right threading and length, I won't tell where you got it. If you find the right screw, just put a washer on it. The combination you have is just to reduce inventory and installation labor.

Was the chair bought at Ikea?

Wonder if it is a two piece bolt?  A hex head set bolt with a locking nut.

It’s a chair I bought online on Amazon and i didn’t know if it makes it better but it’s one screw like welded together maybe? Idk like I said im not very good with screws haha it’s all one screw nothing comes off or anything just straight up one piece. 3 of them hold the back part of the chair together with the bottom half.

It is in a spot where it’ll be hard to get a small wrench in there so an Allen tool is kinda the best tool for screwing it in

Find an Allen Head Cap screw and put a washer on it.

If it's hard to get to, then what you probably need is a Socket Cap Screw (probably with a washer). Which one exactly, only you know, because you need to measure the diameter, length, and thread pitch.

So I finally got word back from the manufacturer that it’s a M8*25 screw.

That only tells you the thread diameter and length—nothing about the thread pitch or head type.  Personally, I'm just getting an M8 bolt (ideally flanged, adding a washer if not) from my nearest hardware store, matching the thread pitch to the existing bolt, and using a socket on it.  I'm 99.9% sure it's got interior and exterior hexes so the manufacturer can include a cheapass Allen wrench with it, since most purchasers are unlikely to have a socket set.

@Huesmann - and maybe have some uses (in furniture) where a little plastic doo-dad can snap into the Allen hole to 'cover up' the screw.

@JonCuster I suppose that's possible too.  Although I'd expect a cover big enough to cover an M8 bolt would snap into the countersink for the bolt, rather than the hex in the head.

Did you stab the screw through a piece of white fabric to get a good shot of the inside of the head?   That my friend wins my heart for today!

@Huesmann M8 tells you all you need to know about thread pitch, insofar as they are pretty standard. (Yes, there’s fine and coarse metric, but for a given size, it’s 99.9% standard. And yes, I made up that stat.)

I would guess that the inside fitting (Allen or Torx) is used in the factory. This is so a robot arm can be preloaded with the screws (held in place with vacuum) and blat in all the screws at once. It then makes sense for the washers to be integral too. I saw video of a BMW cylinder head being factory-fitted with about 20 bolts at once. The plain nut head is for customers who only have a socket set, when it needs tightening or shipping.

Answering based on the question and also OP comments above: the goal is to buy an identical screw for an office chair.
If you don't care about the dual head, it's a common screw.  Take it to any hardware store. They have a gauge where you can easily match the thread by screwing yours into the gauge, and then you pick the right screw from their selection.

It’s a flanged hex-head machine cap screw with an internal hex drive. Breaking that down into pieces:

Hex-head: Should be self explanatory.
Flanged: the circular protrusion at the base of the head is a flange, intended to serve the same purpose as a flat washer. This is usually done to simplify assembly and reduce the total number of items on the bill of materials, though it has other minor advantages as well.
Cap screw: A cap screw has an external head. This largely just distinguishes it from a screw that lacks a head, sometimes known as a set screw, grub screw, or blind screw.
Machine screw: The end of the screw opposite the head is flat and is not self-tapping. This is compared to a typical wood screw, which has a pointed end, or the self-tapping screws often used to mount case fans in desktop computers, both of which are designed to be screwed into things without threading. Machine screws are instead designed to be screwed directly into something that’s threaded, or to be inserted through a hole and have a nut of appropriate size threaded onto the other end.
Internal hex drive: Should also be self-explanatory.

It’s not possible without a size reference to determine the threading, shaft dimensions, or drive dimensions.
As far as a replacement, any reasonable hardware store should be able to match the thread and shaft dimensions for a replacement cap-head machine screw if you simply take the screw in and ask for some help finding a replacement. Unless you care about the drive, you could just as easily get some other type of head/drive and it will work just as well.
